# Scriptable JavaScript interpreter with bindings for PHP or Python?

Tags: php, javascript, python, interpreter

Does anyone know of a JavaScript interpreter that has bindings to PHP or Python?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [pyv8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/) - Google's v8 engine with Python bindings.

Answer (score 2):

Try QtScript, from the Qt library:

```
from PyQt4 import QtScript
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194910/embedded-script-languages-for-php) on embedding various languages into PHP.

re: Javascript in particular, [Pecl Spidermonkey](http://devzone.zend.com/article/4704) is mentioned; otherwise, not much to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

At now there is v8js-0.1.3 (beta) pecl package for PHP5.3.3+
You can easily install it like that (debian/ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install libv8-dev
sudo pecl install v8js-beta
sudo bash -c 'echo "extension=v8js.so" > /etc/php5/mods-available/_pecl.v8js.ini'
sudo ln -s ../mods-available/_pecl.v8js.ini /etc/php5/conf.d/30-v8js.ini
```

I've using _pecl prefix for pecl packages. Of course you can remove or change it as you wish.